# Algolia - WordPress exclude single term from indexing

Tags: php, wordpress, algolia

I am trying to exclude single term "archive" with ID of 3795 from taxonomy of "events_status" from CPT "events". I am getting poppup with empty error when trying to reindex the "events" cpt in the WordPress backend. This is my code:

```
// EXCLUDE TERM FROM BEING INDEXED
function custom_should_index_term( $should_index, WP_Post $post ) {

    $terms_to_exclude = array( 3795 );

    if ( false === $should_index ) {
        return $should_index;
    }


    if ( $post->post_type !== 'events' ) {
        return  $should_index;
    }


    $post_term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'events_status' );
    $remaining_term_ids = array_diff( $post_term_ids, $terms_to_exclude 
   );
    if ( count( $remaining_term_ids ) === 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $should_index;
     }
    add_filter('algolia_should_index_post', 'custom_should_index_term', 
    10, 2);
   add_filter('algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 
   'custom_should_index_term', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it right. wp_get_post_terms() needs also array with which fields we want to get. Since we are comparing the ID's we ask it to get us ID's.

```
// EXCLUDE TERM FROM BEING INDEXED
function custom_should_index_term( $should_index, WP_Post $post ) {

    $terms_to_exclude = array( 3795 );

    if ( false === $should_index ) {
        return $should_index;
    }


    if ( $post->post_type !== 'events' ) {
        return  $should_index;
    }


    $post_term_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'events_status', array("fields" => "ids") );
    $remaining_term_ids = array_diff( $post_term_ids, $terms_to_exclude );
    if ( count( $remaining_term_ids ) === 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $should_index;
}
add_filter('algolia_should_index_post', 'custom_should_index_term', 10, 2);
add_filter('algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 'custom_should_index_term', 10, 2);
```